# jQuery slide in seperate paragraphs in a common div without sliding the whole div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slide

So I have a `div` and in it i have several paragraphs. The `div` has some styling (e.g a background, a border) and the paragraphs live "inside" the `div` like list items.

```
<div id="box">
   <p>'s in here
</div>
```

And I add paragraphs via this code:

```
$("box").append("<p>Some text</p>").hide().slideDown("slow");
```

But when I add a new paragraph the entire `div` "box" gets hidden and then slides down. How do I make it so that only the last paragraph slides down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can create your paragraph as a jQuery object then hide it, then append it to the target div and since you have created the object seperately you now have a reference to that object, so using that object you can easily animate it.

Here is the sample code:

```
var $paragraph = $("<p>Another paragraph</p>").hide();
$("div").append($paragraph);
$paragraph.slideDown();
```

Here is the full example on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/loperavaqu/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1):

use **[last()](https://api.jquery.com/last/)** : Reduce the set of matched elements to the final one in the set.

```
$("box").append("<p>Some text</p>").children().last().hide().slideDown("slow");
```